# Materialize Css Timepicker onSelect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, timepicker, onselect

I'm trying to use Timepicker of [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/pickers.html). I need to use the **onSelect** event but nothing happens.

This is the html :

```
<input type="text" name="time" class="timepicker">
```

This is the javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        onSelect:function(hour,minute){
           alert(hour+" "+minute);
        }
    });
});
```

The timepicker is working very well but when I select time and hour, nothing happens. No error in console and no alert shown...
I tried with the **onCloseEnd** event but nothing happens too.

I need help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the documentation is wrong. I checked the `materialize.js` and found that `timepicker` didn't bind any event such as `onOpenStart`, `onSelect` and `onCloseEnd` but datepicker did.

This snippet shows that the same event but only binding to datepicker.

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  onSelect: function(time) {
    console.log(time)
  }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(time){
    console.log(time)
  }
});
```

```css
.timepicker-modal,
.datepicker-modal{
  top: -5% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="time" class="timepicker">

<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

Here's a demo, showing that none of the events mentioned in the documentation are triggered (They even didn't be registered cause there is no `event` options in timepicker.)

timepicker
[image]

datepicker
[image]

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
  onOpenStart: function(){
    console.log('onOpenStart')
  },
  onOpenEnd: function(){
    console.log('onOpenEnd')
  },
  onCloseStart: function(){
    console.log('onCloseStart')
  },
  onCloseEnd: function(){
    console.log('onCloseEnd')
  },
  onSelect: function(){
    console.log('onSelect')
  },
});

$('.timepicker').on('change', function() {
  console.log('change: ' + this.value)
})
```

```css
.timepicker-modal{
  top: -5% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="time" class="timepicker">
```

The only way success is using `change()` event.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the documentation is wrong ! Let's use change() !

Answer (score 0):

I try this time picker with on change and doesn't work too 
because the input value is equal ''.